# pandas dataframe columns scaling with sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with mixed type columns, and I'd like to apply sklearn's min_max_scaler to some of the columns.  Ideally, I'd like to do these transformations in place, but haven't figured out a way to do that yet.  I've written the following code that works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing

scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

dfTest = pd.DataFrame({'A':[14.00,90.20,90.95,96.27,91.21],'B':[103.02,107.26,110.35,114.23,114.68], 'C':['big','small','big','small','small']})
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

def scaleColumns(df, cols_to_scale):
    for col in cols_to_scale:
        df[col] = pd.DataFrame(min_max_scaler.fit_transform(pd.DataFrame(dfTest[col])),columns=[col])
    return df

dfTest

    A   B   C
0    14.00   103.02  big
1    90.20   107.26  small
2    90.95   110.35  big
3    96.27   114.23  small
4    91.21   114.68  small

scaled_df = scaleColumns(dfTest,['A','B'])
scaled_df

A   B   C
0    0.000000    0.000000    big
1    0.926219    0.363636    small
2    0.935335    0.628645    big
3    1.000000    0.961407    small
4    0.938495    1.000000    small
```

I'm curious if this is the preferred/most efficient way to do this transformation.  Is there a way I could use df.apply that would be better?

I'm also surprised I can't get the following code to work:

```
bad_output = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(dfTest['A'])
```

If I pass an entire dataframe to the scaler it works:

```
dfTest2 = dfTest.drop('C', axis = 1)
good_output = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(dfTest2)
good_output
```

I'm confused why passing a series to the scaler fails.  In my full working code above I had hoped to just pass a series to the scaler then set the dataframe column = to the scaled series.

Comment: Does it work if you do this `bad_output = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(dfTest['A'].values)`? accessing the `values` attribute returns a numpy array, for some reason sometimes the scikit learn api will correctly call the right method that makes pandas returns a numpy array and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Pandas' dataframes are quite complicated objects with conventions that do not match scikit-learn's conventions. If you convert everything to NumPy arrays, scikit-learn gets a lot easier to work with.

Comment: @edChum - `bad_output = in_max_scaler.fit_transform(dfTest['A'].values)` did not work either.  @larsmans - yeah I had thought about going down this route, it just seems like a hassle.  I don't know if it is a bug or not that Pandas can pass a full dataframe to a sklearn function, but not a series.  My understanding of a dataframe was that it is a dict of series.  Reading in the "Python for Data Analysis" book, it states that pandas is built on top of numpy to make it easy to use in NumPy-centric applicatations.

Answer (score 356, accepted):

I am not sure if previous versions of `pandas` prevented this but now the following snippet works perfectly for me and produces exactly what you want without having to use `apply`

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler


>>> scaler = MinMaxScaler()

>>> dfTest = pd.DataFrame({'A':[14.00,90.20,90.95,96.27,91.21],
                           'B':[103.02,107.26,110.35,114.23,114.68],
                           'C':['big','small','big','small','small']})

>>> dfTest[['A', 'B']] = scaler.fit_transform(dfTest[['A', 'B']])

>>> dfTest
          A         B      C
0  0.000000  0.000000    big
1  0.926219  0.363636  small
2  0.935335  0.628645    big
3  1.000000  0.961407  small
4  0.938495  1.000000  small
```

Comment: Neat! A more generalized version `df[df.columns] = scaler.fit_transform(df[df.columns])`

Comment: I know this is a delayed comment from original date, but why is there two square brackets in dfTest[['A', 'B']]? I can see it doesn't work with single bracket, but couldn't understand the reason.

Comment: @RajeshThevar The outer brackets are pandas' typical selector brackets, telling pandas to select a column from the dataframe.  The inner brackets indicate a list.  You're passing a list to the pandas selector.  If you just use single brackets - with one column name followed by another, separated by a comma - pandas interprets this as if you're trying to select a column from a dataframe with multi-level columns (a MultiIndex) and will throw a keyerror.

Comment: to add to @ken's answer if you want to see exactly how pandas implements this indexing logic and why a tuple of values would be interpreted differently than a list you can look at how DataFrames implement the `__getitem__` method. Specifically you can open you ipython and do `pd.DataFrame.__getitem__??` ; after you import pandas as pd of course ;)

Comment: This works great, however when I try to do `scaler.fit()` and `scaler.transform()` on two separate lines I'm getting the dreaded `SettingWithCopyWarning`. Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: A practical note: for those using train/test data splits, you'll want to only fit on your training data, not your testing data.

Comment: `df[df.columns] = scaler.fit_transform(df[df.columns])`  -- perfect @citynorman!

Comment: To scale all but the timestamps column, combine with

`columns =df.columns.drop('timestamps')
df[df.columns] = scaler.fit_transform(df[df.columns]`

Comment: @DavidJ. can you provide a reference for why?

Comment: Correction of @intotecho's comment. You should do `columns = df.columns.drop('timestamps')` and `df[columns] = scaler.fit_transform(df[columns])`. It should be `columns` in the square brackets, not `df.columns`

Comment: How to inverse a value in this way?

Comment: Can use `df[:] = scaler.fit_transform(df)` if scaling the entire dataset.

Comment: @compguy24 The test and validation datasets should not have access to any data from training dataset to prevent the bias, that is why.

Comment: To tranform a single column of the df, you need to use `scaler.fit_transform[['col_1']]`. Double brackets don't go away since they keep the array 2D.

Answer (score 30):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(scale.fit_transform(df.values), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```

This should work without depreciation warnings.

Comment: or
`df[df.columns] = scale.fit_transform(df)`

Comment: Works perfectly! I was trying to figure out how to retain the column names, this helped.

Comment: Tested to have worked on `version 1.5.1`.

Answer (score 26):

Like this?

```
dfTest = pd.DataFrame({
           'A':[14.00,90.20,90.95,96.27,91.21],
           'B':[103.02,107.26,110.35,114.23,114.68], 
           'C':['big','small','big','small','small']
         })
dfTest[['A','B']] = dfTest[['A','B']].apply(
                           lambda x: MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(x))
dfTest

    A           B           C
0   0.000000    0.000000    big
1   0.926219    0.363636    small
2   0.935335    0.628645    big
3   1.000000    0.961407    small
4   0.938495    1.000000    small
```

Comment: I get a bunch of DeprecationWarnings when I run this script. How should it be updated?

Comment: See @LetsPlayYahtzee's answer below

Comment: A simpler version:

dfTest[['A','B']] = dfTest[['A','B']].apply(MinMaxScaler().fit_transform)

Comment: this will instantiate a new MinMaxScaler per row not sure if it matters though

Comment: This looks outdated.

Answer (score 16):

As it is being mentioned in pir's comment - the `.apply(lambda el: scale.fit_transform(el))` method will produce the following warning:

> DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17
>   and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using
>   X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1)
>   if it contains a single sample.

Converting your columns to numpy arrays should do the job (I prefer StandardScaler):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scale = StandardScaler()

dfTest[['A','B','C']] = scale.fit_transform(dfTest[['A','B','C']].as_matrix())
```

-- **Edit** Nov 2018 (Tested for pandas **0.23.4**)--

As Rob Murray mentions in the comments, in the current (v0.23.4) version of pandas `.as_matrix()` returns `FutureWarning`. Therefore, it should be replaced by `.values`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()

scaler.fit_transform(dfTest[['A','B']].values)
```

-- **Edit** May 2019 (Tested for pandas **0.24.2**)--

As joelostblom mentions in the comments, "Since `0.24.0`, it is recommended to use `.to_numpy()` instead of `.values`."

Updated example:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
dfTest = pd.DataFrame({
               'A':[14.00,90.20,90.95,96.27,91.21],
               'B':[103.02,107.26,110.35,114.23,114.68],
               'C':['big','small','big','small','small']
             })
dfTest[['A', 'B']] = scaler.fit_transform(dfTest[['A','B']].to_numpy())
dfTest
      A         B      C
0 -1.995290 -1.571117    big
1  0.436356 -0.603995  small
2  0.460289  0.100818    big
3  0.630058  0.985826  small
4  0.468586  1.088469  small
```

Comment: use `.values` in place of `.as_matrix()` as `as_matrix()` now gives a `FutureWarning`.

Comment: Since `0.24.0`, it is [recommended to use `.to_numpy()` instead of `.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#accessing-the-values-in-a-series-or-index).

Answer (score 10):

You can do it using  `pandas` only:

```
In [235]:
dfTest = pd.DataFrame({'A':[14.00,90.20,90.95,96.27,91.21],'B':[103.02,107.26,110.35,114.23,114.68], 'C':['big','small','big','small','small']})
df = dfTest[['A', 'B']]
df_norm = (df - df.min()) / (df.max() - df.min())
print df_norm
print pd.concat((df_norm, dfTest.C),1)

          A         B
0  0.000000  0.000000
1  0.926219  0.363636
2  0.935335  0.628645
3  1.000000  0.961407
4  0.938495  1.000000
          A         B      C
0  0.000000  0.000000    big
1  0.926219  0.363636  small
2  0.935335  0.628645    big
3  1.000000  0.961407  small
4  0.938495  1.000000  small
```

Comment: I know that I can do it just in pandas, but I may want to eventually apply a different sklearn method that isn't as easy to write myself.  I'm more interested in figuring out why applying to a series doesn't work as I expected than I am in coming up with a strictly simpler solution.  My next step will be to run a RandomForestRegressor, and I want to make sure I understand how Pandas and sklearn work together.

Comment: **This answer is dangerous** because `df.max() - df.min()` can be 0, leading to an exception. Moreover, `df.min()` is computed twice which is inefficient. Note that `df.ptp()` is equivalent to `df.max() - df.min()`.

Answer (score 8):

I know it's a very old comment, but still:

Instead of using single bracket `(dfTest['A'])`, use double brackets `(dfTest[['A']])`.

i.e: `min_max_scaler.fit_transform(dfTest[['A']])`.

I believe this will give the desired result.

Answer (score 6):

(Tested for pandas **1.0.5**)
Based on @athlonshi answer (it had *ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'big'*, on C column), full working example without warning:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scale = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

df = pd.DataFrame({
           'A':[14.00,90.20,90.95,96.27,91.21],
           'B':[103.02,107.26,110.35,114.23,114.68], 
           'C':['big','small','big','small','small']
         })
print(df)
df[["A","B"]] = pd.DataFrame(scale.fit_transform(df[["A","B"]].values), columns=["A","B"], index=df.index)
print(df)

       A       B      C
0  14.00  103.02    big
1  90.20  107.26  small
2  90.95  110.35    big
3  96.27  114.23  small
4  91.21  114.68  small
          A         B      C
0  0.000000  0.000000    big
1  0.926219  0.363636  small
2  0.935335  0.628645    big
3  1.000000  0.961407  small
4  0.938495  1.000000  small
```

Comment: it should be "scale = MinMaxScaler()", instead of "scale = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()"

Answer (score 3):

Using `set_output(transform='pandas')` works on **Sklearn >= 1.2.**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler().set_output(transform='pandas') # set_output works from version 1.2

dfTest = pd.DataFrame({'A':[14.00,90.20,90.95,96.27,91.21],
                       'B':[103.02,107.26,110.35,114.23,114.68], 
                       'C':['big','small','big','small','small']})

dfTest[['A', 'B']] = scaler.fit_transform(dfTest[['A', 'B']])
dfTest.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried applying the `min_max_scaler.fit_transform()` to multiple columns of a  `pd.DataFrame()`

I was getting the following message:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0.31428571 0.32142857 0.288... 0.46428571]
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature...
```

My data really had only one feature (dimension) and so the following approach worked:

```py
columns_to_normalize = ['a', 'b']

min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

for col in columns_to_normalize:
   df[col] = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df[col].values.reshape(-1, 1) )
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```