# MinMaxScaler for a number of columns in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to apply MinmaxScaler on a number of pandas DataFrame 'together'. Meaning that I want the scaler to perform on all data in those columns, not separately on each column.

My DataFrame has 20 columns. I want to apply the scaler on 12 of the columns at the same time. I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645153/pandas-dataframe-columns-scaling-with-sklearn). But it does not solve my problem since it acts on each column separately.

Comment: One way this is done in the industry is to flatten your columns to a 1D array (technically 2D array still), fit and apply transformations, then reshape the array back to the original shape, as I show in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, **you want the `sklearn` scaler to fit and transform multiple columns with the same criteria (in this case min and max definitions).** Here is one way you can do this -

1. You can save the initial shape of the columns and then transform the numpy array of those columns into a 1D array from a 2D array.
2. Next you can fit your scaler and transform this 1D array
3. Finally you can use the old shape to reshape the array back into the n columns you need and save them

**The advantage of this approach is that this works with any of the sklearn scalers you need to use, `MinMaxScaler`, `StandardScaler` etc.**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()

dfTest = pd.DataFrame({'A':[14.00,90.20,90.95,96.27,91.21],
                       'B':[103.02,107.26,110.35,114.23,114.68],
                       'C':['big','small','big','small','small']})

cols = ['A','B']
old_shape = dfTest[cols].shape #(5,2)

dfTest[cols] = scaler.fit_transform(dfTest[cols].to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)).reshape(old_shape)
print(dfTest)
```

```
          A         B      C
0  0.000000  0.884188    big
1  0.756853  0.926301  small
2  0.764303  0.956992    big
3  0.817143  0.995530  small
4  0.766885  1.000000  small
```

Answer (score 1):

you can extract the "min" and "max" statistics from those columns and perform the scaling yourself:

```py
# columns of interest
cols = [...]

# get the minimum and maximum values in that region
vals = df[cols].to_numpy()
min_val = vals.min()
max_val = vals.max()

# scale the region using them
df[cols] = df[cols].sub(min_val).div(max_val - min_val)
```

(`sub` is method way of doing "-" and `div` is for "/".)

Above, `df` is your *training* dataframe; to scale the testing dataframe, you replace `df` with that in the last line, e.g.,

```py
test_df[cols] = test_df[cols].sub(min_val).div(max_val - min_val)
```

instead of extracting min/max of it separately which would leak information from the test set.

Answer (score 0):

Mustafa has a good solution save one needed change:

df[cols].to_numpy().min() gives a **single** minimum value across **all** columns. What you want is the minimum of **each** column. Same for maximum.

You do this by simply using pandas: min_val = df[cols].min(); max_val = df[cols].max(). At that point, the normalization occurs with appropriate min and max values for **each** column and calculates it in a vectorized manner just as Mustafa has it.